# ASP.NET authorization doesn't work in Chrome, IE and Opera

Tags: asp.net

We have a site on asp.net framework 2 (dashCommerce cms)
Month ago we noticed an error — one guy couldnt loggin from chrome on his own laptop. System didnt display any error messages, just redirected on main page in unauthorized state.
We couldnt reproduce the same issue on our computers in the same browser (btw it was chrome)
and decided that it had been connected with some undefinded local issue of that guy's laptop.

But then, i got the same issue on my computer. I couldnt login in the system in chrome. Other browsers worked excellent. And we could see the problem only on my computer. We tested the site on 5 different computers with exactly the same chrome version, and everybody could login excepting me.

It looked like asp.net authorized me successful (because if i entered wrong password i got a message about it) but chrome didnt accept cookies.

At this moment, i have that problem on my two computers, and i cant login using Chrome, IE and Opera. Only FF can login with no issues. 
But other guys can easily login using such browser from them own computers.

We've been already spent almost two week puzzling our heads what the hell is going on. Nothing helps. 
I noticed:
1. Even if i cant login, nevetheless the browser keeps the session — i can add few items in shopping cart and it wont be deleted. I can try to login, then check out the shopping cart and would see those added items.

1. If i change coockieless attribute to «Uri» then authorization worka fine, i can login using all sort of browsers, but in this case the site has terrible links, we cant allow it.

It makes me think that the problem is connected with a session but i cannt understand why i can login from another computer (the same browser, the same Windows7)

Does anybody has any ideas???

Comment: The first thing to do is capture the traffic in a tool like Fiddler. You can then play back the scenario on your debug machine and determine if any of the code might be working differently. This will help determine if the cookie storage in Chrome is the only, and perhaps real, issue.

Comment: Did you tried to change session and forms authentication cookie names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forgot about this question.
We solved the problem: removed standard asp.net auth form and developed common form with manual processing of authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to page caching. You are logged in but receive a cached (not logged in) version of a page.
Try turning kernel mode caching off as a start.
And like Gregory said - capture your requests and see how it works. Pay special attention to set-cookie http headers.